# Error when validating Xtext DSL in standalone Java project

Tags: java, dsl, xtext, emf

I recently followed Sebastian Zarnekow's short guide on how to deploy an Xtext DSL into a standalone project (found here: http://zarnekow.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/how-to-deploy-xtext-standalone.html)

However I receive the following error when attempting to run the project...

"The string resource '_UI_DiagnosticRoot_diagnostic' could not be located"

Could this be something to do with how the JAR is exported, I chose the "Extract required libraries into generated JAR" option, if I try to use the second option where the libraries are packaged into the JAR I receive a different error telling me that a main method could not be found.

Has anyone come across this issue before? I tried updating EMF and Xtext but it didn't seem to have any affect.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should be a "warning" only - maybe logged as error but not prevent the program from running.
the problem is there a multiple plugin.properties in the root of the jars that may override each other. seems one from the org.eclipse.emf.ecore is going lost.

so you may create a plugin.properties that contains this (and maybe other keys) as well.

Comment: Just having that same issue. Where am I supposed to place that file? Do I need to explicitly include it in the maven build definition?

Comment: simply in mydsl/mydsl.ide

Comment: you may also have a look at what xtext new project wizard creates for language server uber/fat jar

Comment: Hey, thanks. I'm not experienced with Java; maybe something simple is escaping me. I did use the new wizard and the added the main class to `maven-assembly-plugin` to achieve an executable. Yet it looks like the properties file is ignored wherever I put it...

Comment: If you use what the wizard creates there should not be an issue